# Python Remove Duplicates From list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

**Please Note, question got fixed.**

In python I have the following list

```
[('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', 1)]
```

How can I remove duplicates where I consider an item to be duplicate if **it has the same 3 first tuples**, so I'm expecting to get the following output:

```
[('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', 1)]
```

as we can find `('admin', 'admin', None)` twice in the original input.

---

The provided and only answer **fails** on the following input:

```
[('admin', '', {'type': 'http_basic', 'login_url': 'https://IP_HERE/AuthChk', 'method': 'get'})]
```

While I'm expecting it to return exactly same list

Same error for:

```
list(set([i for i in lst]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order

Comment: If duplicate has same first 2 elements, why does your expected output look like it does?

Comment: Your result is wrong - all your results have the same 2 first elemets

Comment: `list( set( [('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', 1)] )` ) would give you what you want ... (not order-wise but element-wise) it takes all elements into account.

Comment: @PatrickArtner sorry for the mistake I did, question got updated. please keep your comment for the previous version as it's helpful as well

Comment: Expected output makes even less sense now. you removed the non-duplicate

Comment: @matszwecja you are right, fixed as well sorry for that

Comment: I'm completely lost at this point. None of those has 3 same elements and looks like you reverted your initial correction instead of fixing something else.

Comment: @matszwecja how is that? look at first 2...

Comment: Yeah, all of them has the same 2 values - 'admin' and 'admin'. And you ask about "same 3 first fields".

Comment: I mean look at the first 2 tuples... they are the same so they are replaced by one copy...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = []
first_timers = set()
for i in lst:
    if hash(str(i)) not in first_timers:
        first_timers.add(hash(str(i)))
        result.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem - which was not adequately captured by your simplified example of

```
[('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', None), ('admin', 'admin', 1)]
```

is that your tuple contains non-hash-able datatypes (aka: dict's / set's etc.).

You can transform your inner tuples to stringified versions of it, put them into a dict under that key with the original tuple as value - then use the dict.values() as outputs:

```
data = [('admin', '', {'type': 'http_basic', 'login_url': 'https://IP_HERE/AuthChk', 'method': 'get'}),
    ('admin', '', {'type': 'http_basic', 'login_url': 'https://IP_HERE/AuthChk', 'method': 'get'}),
    ('nonadmin', '', {'type': 'http_basic', 'login_url': 'https://IP_HERE/AuthChk', 'method': 'get'})]

def strKey(whatever):
    return tuple(map(str, whatever))

d = { strKey(inner):inner for inner in data}

uniqified = list(d.values())
print(uniqified)
```

Output:

```
[('admin', '', {'type': 'http_basic', 'login_url': 'https://IP_HERE/AuthChk', 'method': 'get'}),
 ('nonadmin', '', {'type': 'http_basic', 'login_url': 'https://IP_HERE/AuthChk', 'method': 'get'})]
```